# WPF - Bind to MainViewModel property from modal

Tags: wpf, data-binding

It is easy to bind to a property in MainViewModel (MVM) from a button to manipulate whether it is enabled or not:

```
<Button IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsUSBInserted}"/>
```

However, I have a modal pop up (new Window). I would like a button in the pop up window to be controlled by the IsUSBInserted property in MVM as well. Is this possible?

Here's what I am trying to do conceptually (in the pop up XAML):  1) is it possible   2) if so, what is correct syntax as this does not seem to be working.  Thank you.

```
<Window xmlns:mainViewModel="clr-namespace:Acme.MainApp.ViewModel">

<Button IsEnabled="{Binding Path=mainViewModel.IsUSBInserted}"/>
```

Comment: "is it possible" - yes. "what is correct syntax" - `<Button IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsUSBInserted}"/>` provided that you give popup window the same DataContext (MainViewModel )

Comment: @Ash - thank you! Just for completeness for others, I set the DataContext in the pop up Code Behind in the constructor - this.DataContext = MainViewModel ... it is working ... woot !

Answer (score 0):

> I would like a button in the pop up window to be controlled by the IsUSBInserted property in MVM

There are two ways to do this,

1. Provide the viewmodel into the popup's datacontext then bind to the property in question.
2. Create a [dependency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-properties-overview) property on the popup window where one would bind to the VM's property to allow such linkage.